# How to add SQL Server database to my VS11 Website?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I have a website project (C#/ASP.NET) opened in Visual Studio 11 (beta) which works with the built-in SQL Server Compact Edition. But, I would rather use my SQL Server 2012 which is installed on this machine, and I have my tables already created in it.

Question is, how do connect to it from VS11? Do I add it in the `App_Data` folder where I have the Compact database?

Right now I am opening my pre-made database with the

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
```

command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the database created on SQL Server 2012, then just use it!

No need to *add it* to your project (and most definitely don't copy it into `App_Data`!).

Just create a connection string in your `web.config` something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="YourConnectionStringNameHere"
        connectionString="server=(local);database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then use that in your app using all the normal ADO.NET components like `SqlConnection` or `SqlCommand`:

```
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringNameHere"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your-sql-statement-here", conn))    
{
   // do work in your database here....
}
```

Or use something like Entity Framework to make your life even easier!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks @marcs_s for adding the the correct code as well. I tried reading up on the previously supplied links but apparently I was too stupid to do it on my own ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the technique you wish to use to connect to the SQL server database.  I prefer to set my connection string in the web.config and use that when connecting to my database.  There are several options you might want to explore.  Here is a good MSDN article explaining some techniques.

[Connecting to Databases in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371.aspx)